# Turning tables in R into latex

Tags: r, latex

```
  library(tables)
  iris2 <- iris[ iris$Species != 'versicolor', ]
  iris2$Species <- factor(iris2$Species)
  tmp <- tabular( Petal.Width+Petal.Length + Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length ~ Species* (mean+sd),       data=iris2 )

  tmp.p <- sapply( names(iris2)[1:4], function(x) t.test( iris2[[x]] ~ iris2$Species )$p.value )
  tmp

  > tmp

                Species                        
                setosa         virginica       
                mean    sd     mean      sd    
   Petal.Width  0.246   0.1054 2.026     0.2747
   Petal.Length 1.462   0.1737 5.552     0.5519
   Sepal.Width  3.428   0.3791 2.974     0.3225
   Sepal.Length 5.006   0.3525 6.588     0.6359
```

I want to turn my R table into latex code. So I ran

```
 > latex(tmp, file = "")

% latex.default(tmp, file = "") 
%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline\hline
$0.246$&$1.462$&$3.428$&$5.006$&$0.105385589380046$&$0.173663996480184$&$0.379064369096289$&$0.352489687213451$&$2.026$&$5.552$&$2.974$&$6.588$&$0.274650055636667$&$0.551894695663983$&$0.322496638172637$&$0.635879593274432$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{table}
```

This is what R gave me. But the problem is there is only 1 row, when there should actually be at least 5. First row is for the species names, second is petal width, third is petal length, and so on. Does this have to do with `tmp` being class `tabular` and not `table`? What can I change so that the table looks right in latex format? Also, is there a way of writing `mean (sd)` in just one column for setosa's petal width, i.e., `0.246 (0.105)`, instead of having two separate columns?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  The output I get is: `\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Species} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{setosa} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{virginica} \\ 
  & mean & sd & mean & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sd} \\ 
\hline
Petal.Width  & $0.246$ & $0.1054$ & $2.026$ & $0.2747$ \\
Petal.Length  & $1.462$ & $0.1737$ & $5.552$ & $0.5519$ \\
Sepal.Width  & $3.428$ & $0.3791$ & $2.974$ & $0.3225$ \\
Sepal.Length  & $5.006$ & $0.3525$ & $6.588$ & $0.6359$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}` (with newlines that don't show properly in the comment)

Comment: What version of R/version of `tables`/OS are you using?

Comment: I have the latest version of R studio. Just installed the tables package today so I assume that's the latest version as well. And I'm using PC

Comment: Rstudio is not R. What is your R version? See by typing `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

The output you show happens when you call

```
latex.default(tmp, file = "")
```

If you call

```
latex(tmp, file = "")
```

then you get the correct output, because it finds the appropriate method for `tabular` items.

Comment: Hm, but I'm certain that I called the latter. However I am still not getting the correct output.